# Show Countdown after button click

Tags: javascript, countdown

i have code html

```
<div id="container">
    <a href="#container">Show Content</a>
    <div id="content">I am some content!</div>
</div>
```

How to when i click `Show Content` echo countdown (12s) before show `<div id="content">I am some content!</div>`

Give me a example for work. Thanks

Comment: It will probably use sequential calls to *setTimeout* until the time has elapsed, then a final call to show the div. What have you tried so far?

Comment: i don't have knowledge for js. give a example, please. Thanks for feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** Example updated to show elements when the countdown starts and hide them when the countdown ends. When the user clicks on the link, the `countToShow` function is invoked. Immediately the initialy hidden 'ads' element is shown with the command `adsElement.style.display = ''` (which removes the `display: none` style specified inline). When the countdown ends (`remainingSeconds === 0`), I hide the 'ads' element again setting `adsElement.style.display = 'none'`.

Here is an example using the `setInterval` function with possibility to specify the countdown time.

```js
function countToShow(timeInSeconds) {

  var countdownElement = document.getElementById('countdown');
  var contentElement = document.getElementById('content');
  var adsElement = document.getElementById('ads');
  var remainingSeconds = timeInSeconds;

  adsElement.style.display = '';
  countdownElement.innerHTML = remainingSeconds;

  var interval = setInterval(function() {

    countdownElement.innerHTML = --remainingSeconds;

    if (remainingSeconds === 0) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      contentElement.style.display = '';
      adsElement.style.display = 'none';
    }

  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <a href="#container" onclick="countToShow(12)">Show Content</a>
  <div id="ads" style="display: none">
    <div id="countdown"></div>
    <div>Ads</div>
  </div>
  <div id="content" style="display: none">I am some content!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for support. How to show more div when click `#container` as: click `#container` show more `div ads` + `countdown` / whent done `countdown` hide `div ads`?

Comment: I've update the answer to fit your requirements.

Comment: again! Thanks for support.

Answer (score 0):

Your div(content) is not hidden and hence will be there on the screen already. First hide the div by using:

```
<div id="content" style="display: none">I am some content!</div>
```

Now add a `onclick` event to the show content div:

```
<a href="#container" onclick="showDiv()">Show Content</a>
```

Define the `showDiv` function:

```
var showDiv = function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('container').style.display = '';  //Edit suggested by RobG
    }, 12000);
}
```

Comment: Consider `style.display = ''` so that the element adopts its default or inherited display value.

Comment: @RobG yeah I geuss that'd be better than defining it here.

Comment: give me a exaple in https://jsfiddle.net/f4qg9vf1/ ,pls. i have add but don't display

Comment: I have edited the same jsfiddle. Have a look. @DinhTv

Answer (score 0):

You can use javaScript `window.setTimeout` function with recursive call to same timeout function until counter reach to 0;

```js
var ctr = 12;

function showTimer(){
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    if(ctr >= 0) {
      document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = ctr + 's';     
      showTimer();
      ctr--; 
    }
  }, 500);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <a href="#container" onClick="showTimer()">Show Content</a>
    <div id="counter"></div>
    <div id="content">I am some content!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How to click `Show Content` echo `<div id="counter"></div>` (hide `<div id="content">I am some content!</div>` ) and done counter (12s) show `<div id="content">I am some content!</div>`. Thanks